# Add plus 1 in a workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I am trying to create a Workflow. It's three columns in one list that needs to have a specific value which a created without problem.

But if these match I need to add 1 (plus 1) in a column in another list.

Is it possible?

Comment: you want to create another item or update an existing item in another list?

Comment: In an existing item

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. get the item value and store it in a variable (Action: Set Workflow Variable)
2. Do a calculation on the variable (Action: Do Calculation)
3. Update the item with the new value (Action: Update List Item)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try

Comment: Worked fine, thanks:)